# Why does Laravel Livewire test with PHPUnit return a NotFoundHttpException when API returns all User records?

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-livewire

I'm having trouble running a test on my API that returns all records from the user model. It's simple. The goal is to retrieve all data from this model. It is working fine both in the browser, in any mode, and in Postman. It always returns the data as JSON. Perfect. That's it.
I created both the tests and controllers with Livewire. I'm using the latest version of Laravel, Livewire, etc.
I'll share with you guys, the code of the controller that works perfectly, as well as the test code, my routes file, etc.
First, here's the error message that appears in my test.

I have already changed the order of routes, I have placed the route in the `routes/web.php` file. I have cleared the `config:clear`, `cache`, etc. I have used the named route, I have undone the named route.
I have tested it in Postman and in any browser. It works.
It is not a Unit test. It is a Feature Test.
It should return the status 200, and the test should not fail with the 404 error.

Please Help.

```bash
user@server:/var/www/virtual-card$ sudo php artisan test --filter ApiBuzCardTest::the_api_return_all_users

FAIL  Tests\Feature\Livewire\Api\ApiBuzCardTest
⨯ the api return all users                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.08s  
─────────────────────────────────────────────
FAILED  Tests\Feature\Livewire\Api\ApiBuzCardTest > the api return all users                                                                                                                                                              NotFoundHttpException  
GET https://server/virtual-card/api/users

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php:51
47▕         $handler = $this->container->make(ExceptionHandler::class);
48▕
49▕         $handler->report($e);
50▕
➜  51▕         $response = $handler->render($passable, $e);
52▕
53▕         if (is_object($response) && method_exists($response, 'withException')) {
54▕             $response->withException($e);
55▕         }

      +42 vendor frames 

43  tests/Feature/Livewire/Api/ApiBuzCardTest.php:17

Tests:    1 failed (0 assertions)
Duration: 0.12s
```

My Controller File: `app/Http/Livewire/Api/ApiBuzCard.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Api;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Jetstream\Features;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Livewire\Component;

class ApiBuzCard extends Component
{
    public function getAllUsers()
    {
      $users = User::orderByDesc('id')->get()->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

      return response($users, 200);
    }
```

My Route File: `routes/api.php`

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Livewire\Api\ApiBuzCard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('users', [ApiBuzCard::class, 'getAllUsers'])->name('api.users');

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')
    ->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

Route::get('user/{id}', [ApiBuzCard::class, 'getUser']);

Route::post('users', [ApiBuzCard::class, 'createUser'])
    ->middleware('api');
Route::put('user/{id}', [ApiBuzCard::class, 'updateUser'])
    ->middleware('api');
Route::delete('user/{id}', [ApiBuzCard::class, 'deleteUser'])
    ->middleware('api');
```

My Test File tests/Feature/ApiBuzCardTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Livewire\Api;

use App\Http\Livewire\Api\ApiBuzCard;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Livewire;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ApiBuzCardTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test */
    public function the_api_return_all_users()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $user = User::factory()->create();

        $response = $this->get('/api/users');
        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

Comment: You did not share the most important part... the test...

Comment: @matiaslauriti Sorry for this mistake. I edited and provided the code above.

Comment: So, `getJson` recives a URL, with headers and JSON ENCODE options... You are passing a URL, an array with a message (that is a header, but I am assuming you want to pass that to the controller, it will not work because it is a GET method, not POST), and then you are passing `2` (I have no idea what `2` is as a JSON ENCODE flag), but it will still make no sense, because again, you cannot JSON encode as you are using GET, so you are not sending anything, just appending to the URL...

Comment: One more thing, I am checking the results of the test and I see no error at all, did you by mistake remove it from there? Can you check again if you have any exception back? And one more question, you are using `actingAs($user, 'web')`, but you are making a request to `/api`, do you have `/api` as `web` guard too? You are mixing them

Comment: Thank you @matiaslauriti. I posted one of the many ways I tried to make the test work. What I want is to pass the test with a 200 status code. I will edit it to show how I am currently doing it. I have been trying for a long time to make this test work.
That's because I'm receiving this "notfound" exception. I was guessing that I'm unable to pass the test because I have my API route in the "routes/api.php" file, and there's no "routes/web.php" file, which would be the default file for routes.

Comment: Having `routes/api.php` does not mean that it is going to be `/api/xxxxxxx`, you have to check the `RouteServiceProvider.php` inside `app/Providers`. There you should have a definition with a `prefix('api')` or something like that. You mentioned that when not using the test, the exact same route works, but when you use a test, it fails. Did you try `->getJson('/api/users');` instead of `->get()`? (on the previous example you have, you had other stuff on `->getJson()`, try it with just the URL).

Comment: You could try writting `$this->artisan('route:list');` on the test to see what routes does the test see. Remember to never run `php artisan config:cache` or `php artisan optimize`, when you run tests, that could create a lot of problems, you must have no cache at all

Comment: This route is correct in the browser and in Postman. It is returning my JSON and displaying the "200 OK" status. I am trying to write a test that achieves the same result as in Postman in this case.
This is the result when I use the method $this->withoutExceptionHandling();.

FAILED  Tests\Feature\Livewire\Api\ApiBuzCardTest > the api return all users                                                                                                                                                              NotFoundHttpException   
  GET https://devlab03.mshome.net/virtual-card/api/users

Comment: You should never use `$this->withoutExceptionHandling()` as the test will fail with weird stuff or just fail altogheter when the framework may resolve the exception, so the test is not 100% right. Always test without it. But try wha I have mentioned, run `route:list` on the test as the first line to see the output and see what routes it is listing.

Comment: I edited and inserted your suggestions into the test, but it still displays: "Expected response status code [200] but received 404. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404."

Comment: I think I know what the issue may be. I think you are mixing Livewire with a normal laravel route. I have never used Livewire, and I hate it honestly, I prefer writting my own routes and controllers and using Vue or React (if not Blade) and interact with it myself. I am checking the documentation, and when you want to test a component (you are extending a component, not a controller), you use `Livewire::test(xxxx)`, not `$this->get` or whatever. And you are setting a method of a COMPONENT as a route CONTROLLER, I think you are mixing everything and is not going to work at all

Comment: Check the documentation: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/testing

Comment: I'm extremely grateful. I had already used the lines below without success:

$response = $this->getJson(route('api.users'));
$response->assertOk();

I have already printed out the documentation for Livewire and Laravel to make it easier for me to understand better. I will continue with the mission, but I will use your approach. I will use the Livewire syntax. Thank you very much for your attention. God bless you.

Comment: No worries at all. Let me know if you were able to create a test with `Livewire::test` and it works as you are expecting. If that happens, post it as an answer on this question (post a literal answer, not a comment nor edit the question) and show us how you did it. I am very ignorant about Livewire as I did use it in the past a little bit and I did not like the approach, so I took another path to solve the issue that Livewire is solving. Let me know what happens so I also learn!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution on the link below. The User Sergiu17 suggested that the problem was the following configuration in my phpunit.xml file:

```
<server name="APP_URL" value="http://devlab03.mshome.net/virtual-card"/>
```

It needs to be changed to `<env name="APP_URL" value="https://localhost"/>`
Although I couldn't find anything in the official documentation, I believe that the Laravel testing environment can only work with this configuration on localhost.
Thank you.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/laravel-feature-tests-always-return-404